# My Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless adopter is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Vendor: Lenovo Model:E41-25)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04

My Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless adapter is not working. In that I can't use WiFi in my Ubuntu 20.04 version. Also my laptop vendor is Lenovo(Model:E41-25) Already I referred some of the solutions here on AskUbuntu.

I can use my WiFi adopter in Windows but not in Ubuntu.

I'm searching this for more than 4 months Still I didn't get the solution.

Please help to find the solution.

**When I'm running** `sudo apt-get update`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ sudo apt-get update
#details done
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$
```

**When I'm running** `lspci`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev ea)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15b3
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Platform Security Processor
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio Dummy Host Bridge
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 4b)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4b)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney HT Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney Address Maps
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney DRAM Configuration
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney Miscellaneous Configuration
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney PM Configuration
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Stoney NB Performance Monitor
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$
```

**When running** `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38a6]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$
```

**While running** `rfkill list`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$
```

**While running** `inxi -F`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ inxi -F
System:
  Host: wintersoldier Kernel: 5.4.0-47-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 81FS v: Lenovo E41-25 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0K88286 WIN 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: LENOVO v: 7UCN28WW(V2.02) 
  date: 11/14/2019 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 43.2 Wh condition: 44.6/48.0 Wh (93%) 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: AMD PRO A4-4350B R4 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G 
  bits: 64 type: MCP L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
  Speed: 1297 MHz min/max: 1300/2500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1297 2: 1297 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] driver: amdgpu 
  v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: amdgpu resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD STONEY (DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-47-generic LLVM 10.0.0) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 20.0.8 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: AMD Family 15h Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-47-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  driver: r8169 
  IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: 9c:5a:44:4a:22:7a 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter 
  driver: N/A 
  Device-3: Qualcomm Atheros type: USB driver: btusb 
  IF-ID-1: bnep0 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A 
  mac: 3c:91:80:66:e9:1c 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 48.09 GiB (10.3%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ01ABF050 size: 465.76 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 37.30 GiB used: 7.38 GiB (19.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7 
  ID-2: /home size: 136.79 GiB used: 7.15 GiB (5.2%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda9 
  ID-3: swap-1 size: 7.63 GiB used: 6.8 MiB (0.1%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda8 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 59.2 C mobo: N/A gpu: amdgpu temp: 59 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 220 Uptime: 1h 33m Memory: 3.73 GiB used: 1.62 GiB (43.4%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38 
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$
```

**While running** `ifconfig`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ ifconfig
bnep0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.44.195  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.44.255
        inet6 fe80::7c9f:4917:c300:61ff  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:91:80:66:e9:1c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20703  bytes 19297996 (19.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15228  bytes 2641916 (2.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 9c:5a:44:4a:22:7a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4353  bytes 378490 (378.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4353  bytes 378490 (378.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$
```

**While running** `iwconfig`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

bnep0     no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
```

**While Running** `dkms status`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ dkms status
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$
```

Note: Nothing shows while running this command - `dkms status`

**While Runnig** `dmesg | grep ath`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ dmesg | grep ath
[    5.689125] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
[    5.726047] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service:9: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/teamviewerd.pid → /run/teamviewerd.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
[   12.054173] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to iomap BAR0
[   12.054223] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: failed to claim device: -5
[   12.054308] ath10k_pci: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
[   78.643772] audit: type=1107 audit(1601128160.462:52): pid=663 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.16" pid=1817 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=664 peer_label="unconfined"
[   79.186168] audit: type=1107 audit(1601128161.006:53): pid=663 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=1817 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=693 peer_label="unconfined"
[   79.187068] audit: type=1107 audit(1601128161.006:54): pid=663 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=1817 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=693 peer_label="unconfined"
[   79.343785] audit: type=1107 audit(1601128161.162:55): pid=663 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=1817 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=693 peer_label="unconfined"
[   79.345006] audit: type=1107 audit(1601128161.166:56): pid=663 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=1817 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=693 peer_label="unconfined"
```

**While Running** `modinfo ath10k_pci`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ modinfo ath10k_pci
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-47-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-6.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac WLAN PCIe/AHB devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     51F04E4FC0190954FF7DF5E
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000050sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000042sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000046sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000056sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000040sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000041sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00000777d000011ACsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ath10k_core
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_pci
vermagic:       5.4.0-47-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        60:9F:61:6A:D4:C9:3C:64:35:01:B1:13:6F:DD:36:46:DB:88:1D:84
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      61:51:18:1B:01:A1:62:8D:09:69:35:76:A8:3F:AE:1B:FC:DE:C4:57:
        29:50:B5:88:D1:5B:8C:72:7B:C0:25:AB:FD:1D:C5:AD:DB:94:57:76:
        9A:02:E1:E8:2E:04:B8:99:31:8D:73:68:3E:B4:66:5E:7B:E5:A6:3C:
        E9:FA:1C:AD:06:04:F7:C9:7D:E8:AB:B8:33:7E:35:03:19:E9:81:DF:
        17:4E:73:45:03:DC:AB:3C:60:E4:8F:F8:86:23:87:12:09:F8:6B:D3:
        40:23:E0:7F:E5:6D:63:ED:D5:0E:57:19:93:8F:A7:06:1A:7C:67:FF:
        B2:E8:C1:F7:C8:2C:13:D6:56:65:8A:70:62:A6:83:F0:1C:BE:F5:BD:
        CC:6F:38:46:F3:A6:F2:4B:84:B1:55:9B:D4:D3:74:2F:3C:08:7C:19:
        2F:78:B6:D1:95:4D:89:1D:0B:81:D5:15:15:75:59:F5:8C:2A:C8:B2:
        AC:51:0F:5E:72:46:4A:A2:52:B3:0D:E1:E0:41:F6:3B:D3:36:D7:6B:
        C3:33:AF:1A:DE:28:2C:BA:D8:D3:6E:80:56:A7:7C:1E:EF:FF:DA:F9:
        5D:7D:50:75:0E:2F:F9:6E:8A:E0:E6:5C:5D:89:8C:AA:F2:6B:2B:59:
        74:1D:FE:6B:7C:1B:07:CA:6F:1B:88:95:6E:92:39:84:07:27:86:49:
        CB:17:8D:A5:47:9F:67:EF:FA:AA:08:7E:1E:DC:4D:1D:E5:21:86:DB:
        FC:F9:E4:26:23:16:08:1E:52:2E:66:23:0E:0B:9B:7B:93:F1:22:4E:
        8A:FF:F0:86:0E:54:98:20:20:4A:2B:E7:DC:A9:B9:A9:99:92:BA:F7:
        5D:BC:5A:A8:FE:BD:30:F6:6B:B8:53:28:96:BC:D8:E3:47:24:C1:4C:
        F5:CF:50:3C:8A:64:2C:F8:91:0E:97:EE:95:4F:96:71:90:DE:0E:3A:
        AA:D1:C4:D0:E1:A8:45:86:09:6E:3E:75:8D:1B:3D:5B:E0:C7:5D:5B:
        6E:B8:36:BF:E8:C3:64:0C:A9:56:F5:7F:C7:62:66:67:12:F8:28:ED:
        A6:C3:29:31:B2:91:4D:21:22:5B:D0:2B:3F:49:7A:29:73:D2:F7:9F:
        F9:0B:76:9E:23:32:3B:B1:8A:A9:E5:89:55:D2:AB:94:65:49:A3:64:
        02:16:DA:87:E5:AA:5A:F1:59:75:C8:EC:88:BD:AE:21:D6:0C:BC:93:
        F4:28:20:FA:EB:3D:4E:5A:AC:64:6F:AA:05:AC:B4:0B:70:E2:06:44:
        E9:FF:2D:3D:DE:C8:F4:6B:01:1F:8A:59:0C:E2:11:50:0E:38:77:70:
        E7:FC:A0:E9:37:E6:C8:7A:AF:56:2D:35
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$
```

While Running `echo "options ath9k_pci irq_mode=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k-pci.conf`

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ echo "options ath9k_pci irq_mode=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k-pci.conf
[sudo] password for wintersoldier: 
options ath9k_pci irq_mode=1
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$
```

Comment: Please edit to include results for `dkms status; dmesg | grep ath; modinfo ath10k_pci`

Comment: I did that. Please check out and help me. I hope you or anyone of you help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: To let Jeremy31 know that you've responded to their request, start comments with @Jeremy31 so they'll get notified.

Comment: Try in terminal `echo "options ath9k_pci irq_mode=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k-pci.conf` reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 I did that you can see that in last of the section. Please see that and help me.

Comment: @Jeremy31 please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: @heynnema can you please help me still I'm searching for solutions

Comment: Send @Jeremy31 another message.

Comment: @heynnema not much either of us can do to fix,  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1872055  The upstream kernel devs might be able to fix

Comment: @iamramanavenkat Boot to a Ubuntu Live 20.10 USB and see if that works. If not, we'll try a newer kernel. Report back. Start comments to me with "@heynnema" or I'll miss them.

Comment: Ok @heynnema Now I'm using WSL while I'm coming back to Ubuntu I'll try 20.10

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following in a terminal. It comes from [here](https://github.com/satishbabariya/qualcomm-atheros-QCA9377-wireless-patch).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
tar zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120

make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install

git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/WLAN.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin

sudo reboot
```

Comment: While I'm doing the same I'm facing the error I mentioned below.
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~/backports-20151120$ make defconfig-wifi
Generating local configuration database from kernel ...mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_3879’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_3881’: Permission denied
(---continuing ---)
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_3971’: Permission denied
Kernel version parse failed!
make: *** [Makefile:42: defconfig-wifi] Error 1
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~/backports-20151120$

Comment: @lamramanavenkat Have you disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: Yes. I disabled secure boot and I'm using UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `acpi=off` or any other `acpi` parameters in the kernel boot loader?

If yes, use `acpi_osi=!`  instead.

Comment: How to to that?

Comment: How to do that? I'm newbie to linux

Answer (score 0):

hey i have the same problem, and what i do is to delete ath10k_pci from /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf. Use the command below:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf
```

and then delete ath10k_pci

Comment: and it solved for me

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the periodic and chaotic "disappearance" of the WiFi adapter atheros qca9377.
I spent a decent amount of time searching for a solution to the problem, everything found on the Internet was reduced to manipulations with linux-drivers and with zero result in my case.
Out of desperation, I decided to switch the mouse from WiFi to Bluetooth (and remove WiFi-"whistle" of mouse from USB-port) - and a miracle happened, the problem went away.
Apparently some ubuntu updates led to a conflict between the laptop's WiFi- module and the WiFi-"whistle" of mouse.

Answer (score -1):

### Solution

- Go to your BIOS
- Enable PXE Boot reboot again.
- Go to BIOS again and put PXE BOOT as first priority then ur OS
- Save and exit.

### Explanation

- Setting PXE boot as First.
- Will enable/prepare the Hardware.
- Then, Leave enabled to OS.