# mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_3983’: Permission denied Kernel version parse failed! - I'm trying to install wifi backports

Tags: networking, 12.04, wireless, gnome-terminal

I'm getting the following error in my terminal while installing backports for My wifi adapter.

My askubuntu question is [My Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless adopter is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Vendor: Lenovo Model:E41-25)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277359/my-qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-adopter-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/)

I'm using the kernel version:

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ uname -s -r
Linux 5.8.12-050812-generic
```

My error is:

```
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ cd backports-20151120
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~/backports-20151120$ make defconfig-wifi
Generating local configuration database from kernel ...mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4206’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4208’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4210’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4212’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4214’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4216’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4219’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4221’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4223’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4225’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4227’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4229’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4231’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4233’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4235’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4237’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4239’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4241’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4243’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4245’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4247’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4249’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4251’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4253’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4255’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4257’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4259’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4261’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4263’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4265’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4268’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4270’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4272’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4274’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4276’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4278’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4280’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4282’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4284’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4286’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4288’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4290’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4292’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4294’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4296’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4298’: Permission denied
Kernel version parse failed!
make: *** [Makefile:42: defconfig-wifi] Error 1
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~/backports-20151120$
```

Please help me to sort out my problem

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot create directories in the kernel source tree because the files in `/usr/src` are all owned by the superuser (`root`).**

I tried the following modification to the script in [your other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277359/my-qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-adopter-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/):

```
tar zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz # like original
cd backports-20151120 # like original
sudo rsync -axvH /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r` /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`.backup # make a backup copy first
sudo chown -vR $USER /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r` # change ownership of all kernel headers
make defconfig-wifi # resume script
```

Now, this fails with the same `Generating local configuration database from kernel ...Kernel version parse failed!` but without the `cannot create directory` errors.

The backport you're trying to install follows [this script](https://github.com/satishbabariya/qualcomm-atheros-QCA9377-wireless-patch) which was created in 2016; are you sure you need to build the kernel? (My stock install has firmware for the QCA9377):

```
ls -lR /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/
```

Comment: `
`
`wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$ ls -lR /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 24 07:31 hw1.0

/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0:
total 2404
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 304308 Aug 19 23:47 board-2.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8124 Aug 19 23:47 board.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 605920 Sep 24 07:31 firmware-5.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 783336 Aug 19 23:47 firmware-5.bin.orig
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 751436 Aug 19 23:47 firmware-6.bin.orig
wintersoldier@wintersoldier:~$
`